# C++ fill a map<string,vector<int>>

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I have two stl containers:

```
vector<vector<int>> numbers;
vector<string> names;
```

How can I save the data from them to map, where string is a key and vector a value?
I tried this:

```
map<string, vector<string>> names_numbers;
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        names_numbers[names[i]] = numbers[i];
    }
```

The size of vectors is the same. However I always get this error:

```
Error   3   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of typ 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

One option how to fill map is do it using = operand:

```
map[key] = value;
```

Why this fails?

Comment: Show the declaration of `meno_cisla`.

Comment: Are you using `using namespace std;`? Because then the compiler things it's `std::map[key]` instead of `map[key]`.

Comment: Yes I'm using it. How can I solve it without stopping using that namespace?

Comment: `using namespace std` has nothing to do with this operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map<string, vector<string>> names_numbers;
```

You have declared map taking value as vector of strings whereas you are inserting into it a vector of ints.

```
names_numbers[names[i]] = numbers[i]; <<< It's a vector of int's.
vector<vector<int>> numbers;
```

Answer (score 3):

You try to assign `vector<int>`, but `names_numbers` values are of type `vector<string>`.